# Dividing a string in sections

Tags: php, string, parsing

What I want to do is take a string and divide it in smaller sections. The input strings have a fixed structure:

```
{something here}loremipsum;loremipsum2;{something else here} ...
```

What I would like to do is to create a substring every time I find a bracket or a ";", i.e.:

```
{ something here }
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum 2
{ something else here }
```

The PHP code I've written until now doesn't always work well, meaning that sometimes I get something like `{something here}loremipsum` as a single section, when it should be divided into two sections.

```
public function divide() {
    $item = "";
    $splitted_instructions = str_split($this->instructions);
    for($i=0; $i<count($splitted_instructions); $i++) {
        if ($splitted_instructions[$i] == "{") {
            while ($splitted_instructions[$i+1] != "}") {
                $i++;
                $item .= $splitted_instructions[$i];
            }
            $item = "{" . $item . "}";
            $items[] = $item;
            $item = "";
        } else {
            while ($splitted_instructions[$i+1] != ";" && $i<count($splitted_instructions)) {
                $i++;
                $item .= $splitted_instructions[$i];
            }
            $items[] = $item;
            $item = "";
        }
    }
    print_r($items);
}
```

Of course, if there is a better way to do it, please let me know :)

Comment: I'm not sure of the full code, but I would expect that multiple calls to `explode` and possibly `implode` could do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$parts = preg_split("/((?<=\\})|\\;|(?=\\{))/", $source, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

It splits the `$source` by the delimiter defined by the regular expression: that is, by one of the following:

1. A cursor position which is preceded by a `}` character
2. `;` character
3. A cursor position which is followed by a `{` character

[`Working DEMO`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C9UfNT)

Comment: That's making some assumptions about that "fixed structure", for example that there can be no `}` in-between the `;` sections... But overall yes, nicer solution than mine. :)

Comment: @deceze Without such assumptions the problem is not defined well enough. For example, without such assumptions it is not clear how should we split e.g. this string: `a;{b;c};d`; both `['a', '{b', 'c}', 'd']` and `['a', 'b;c', 'd']` seem to equally fit as answers.

Comment: @penartur you are right, I should have explained it better. In your example, the splitting should be like this: a, {b;c}, d. Meaning, every time I find a bracket, that should be a different section.

Comment: @user1301428 And what about e.g. `a;{b;c;d`?

Comment: @penartur that cannot happen, an open bracket will always have a matching closing bracket

Comment: @diEcho what do the two # mean?

Comment: this is [`delimiter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 1):

A simple application of regular expressions:

```
$string = preg_replace('/({.*?})(.*?);(.*?);({.*?})/', "\\1\n\\2\n\\3\n\\4\n", $string);
```